# How to wrap BOOL in NSValue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Having trouble wrapping a BOOL value in NSValue.

I tried this:

```
[NSValue valueWithPointer:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

An `NSNumber` *is* an `NSValue` subclass. As such,`[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` is already wrapping it in an `NSValue` for you.

Comment: If you actually want to use an NSValue check my answer below. NSValue is lighter weight when you don't need the extra features NSNumber provides.

Answer (score 2):

Actually NSNumber is a heavier-weight descendant of NSValue. If you actually want to use an NSValue here's how you'd do that:

```
BOOL bool_value = YES;
[NSValue valueWithBytes:&bool_value objCType:@encode(BOOL)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example code to expand on answer by Joshua Weinberg.

➤ To convert a primitive BOOL to a pseudo-Boolean object:

```
NSNumber* isWinning = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
```

➤ To convert a pseudo-Boolean object to a primitive BOOL:

```
BOOL winner = [isWinning boolValue];
```

See [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Objective-C literal:

```
@(YES)
```